# how to make grid mesh conform to topo

Tags: modeling

After adding  a height map  to my plane via displacement modifier I get a nice 3d representation of topo in object mode. But when I switch to edit mode the grid lies flat on a flat plane. There must be a simple command to show the grid in 3d while in edit mode?

Answer (score 2):

In the Displace Modifier panel enable the option **Display modifier in Edit mode**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but it didn't make the vertices jump to conform to the surface. Also this must be a newer version than my Blender 2.79. But after a lot of fussing i discovered that clicking the "apply" button on the displacement modifier did what i wanted.